# How to maintain log audited for all field in one page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want to maintain a **Log table for every field updation**. There are *20-30 field* in one page. For each field i have to maintain the log. Which means if someone change some perticular `launchDate` or something, I need to keep log for that who made that change and time.

Any suggestion will be helpfull.I didn't find any question related to this in SO that's why i am posting this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can go for cron job to update log table

Comment: Can you please explain a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `$diff = array_diff( $original , Input::all() );` exactly not returns as i want.

So, I am doing this in this following process::

I am using two table for this, *one table* ( called `pf_account_log_data` AS *1st table* ) where all posted data stored in *JSON* format with account_id column. *Another table* ( called `pf_account_log_field_by_user` AS *2nd table* ) for which field is being updated and by whoom, which date.

When someone clicks on **SAVE** button i am checking in my *1st table* that is any submitted data is present for that account_id or not. If present then running a foreach loop and chekcing each value corresponding to current posted data and if not equal to previously posted data then i am saving that key with logged_in user_id, time, previous value, current value to *2nd table*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table in your database where you intend to store the log data, the easiest way to capture all the changes is to store the input posted to the page (e.g. `Input::all()`) to a column.

If you want to be efficient in what you store, you can do a diff on the original fields vs new / changed fields:

```
// switch parameters around depending on what data you want to log
$diff = array_diff( $original , Input::all() );

// store $diff to DB, e.g. as JSON
```